# Integral closure and algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, field-theory, integral-extensions

Consider integral domains $A$ and $B$ and their field of fractions $F(A)$ and $F(B)$. According to wikipedia, if $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in an algebraic closure $L$ of $F(A)$, then $L=F(B)$.

**Question 1:** Which book states this result? I need a reference for this result.

**Question 2:** Is the converse true? When $F(B)$ is the algebraic closure of $F(A)$, is true that $B$ is the integral closure of $A$? If the answer is yes, then a reference of the proof will also be considered an answer.

It has been difficult to find a good reference so I need a hand with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For qstn 1 pick an element in F(B). This element is of the form a/b where a,b are algebraic over F(A) Hence a/b is in L. Now pick an element l in L. Consider the minimal polynomial of the element in L. Multiply by suitable constant to get the element cl which is integral over A. one choice of c would be (coefficient of highest degree term * product of denominators of all the nonzero coefficients)^degree of minimal polynomial. The c u chose belongs to A. and cl belongs to B. Thus l belongs to F(B).

As for the second it is not true. Just adjoin another element from the algebraic closure to the integral closure.

Comment: Could you elaborate more in the second question? It is not quite clear for me how your argument works.

Comment: Consider Z as ur A and the set of algebraic integers. call this set B. Now consider B[1/sqrt2] so the field of fractions of B[1/sqrt2] is still the field of algebraic numbers. But B[1/sqrt2] is not the algebraic closure of Z.